# App crash on API 16 Phone when add drawable background on LinearLayout

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout, android-drawable

When adding a drawable frame background in LinearLayout, the APP will crash on API 16 19 (Tested) but works on API 21 27.  The LineayLayout is an item view in recyclerView and there is no animation for this background, it should work for all API level

```
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorGreen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorGreen</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small"
android:background="@drawable/bg_frame_rounded_transparent_strokegreens"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

bg_frame_rounded_transparent_strokegreens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="?attr/colorPrimary">
            </stroke>

        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/item_change_txv_corner_radius"
            android:topRightRadius="@dimen/item_change_txv_corner_radius"
            android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/item_change_txv_corner_radius"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/item_change_txv_corner_radius"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

error:

```
07-30 16:51:26.794 4526-4526/io.ionic.parkstash_parking_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at io.ionic.parkstash_parking_app.view.addparking.SelfParkingListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(SelfParkingListAdapter.java:53)
    at io.ionic.parkstash_parking_app.view.addparking.SelfParkingListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(SelfParkingListAdapter.java:27)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:811)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
    at android.view.Choreographer$C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used `?attr/colorPrimary` as your colour but this is only available on older APIs if you are using an AppCompat theme. Check your theme has a parent that is from AppCompat.

Comment: Hi I have use AppCompat theme and the parent is from AppCompat, but still can't use `?attr/colorPrimary`, but it works when using custom defined color